# Library to parse CSV files, that is compatible with Angular 13+

Tags: angular, parsing, angular13, csv-parser

I am making an Angular 13 project to parse CSV files but I am unable to find a package to parse the CSV Files, the ones I found by googling like "ngx-csv-parser" are not compatible with Angular 13.

Can somebody please suggest a package compatible with Angular 13, I am new to Angular so I am not able to decide which package to use for my project?

Comment: I am also interested! I follow your question waiting for the help of colleagues who have used it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried `ngx-papaparse`. It works fine with me. Here is the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-papaparse).